# How to start a virtual environment for django on windows which created in mac

Tags: python-venv

I have cloned a django project from github, there the virtual environment is created on Mac, so there is no Scripts directory, how can i start the environment on my windows machine.

In mac we start it with "source env\bin\activate" but in windows it is not working

Comment: Python virtual environments are not "portable". So you can not what you want to do. You need to create a new virtual environments with the same dependencies. Typically you would create a `requirements.txt` file for this. -- Here is the documentation for venv https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html -- Here is doc about `requirements.txt` files: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files